# transparent process creation for cocoa components

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, ipc

I have an application *A* which may or may not need to spawn an application *B* and will communicate with it using remote messaging (via *NSConnection*s etc.).

While i know how to do this if *B* is started first, i wonder:
What is a clean cocoa-based approach of transparently starting *B* on demand?

*(For those familiar with COM, i am effectively looking for a `CoCreateInstance()` equivalent)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a GUI app, you could do something like this for 10.6:

```
NSArray * runningBs = [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.example.B"];
if ([runningBs count] == 0) {
  NSURL * bURL = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.example.B"];
  NSRunningApplication * b = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplicationAtURL:bURL options:NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault configuration:nil error:nil];
}
```

For 10.5:
Use `-[NSWorkspace launchedApplications]` and iterate through the array to see if you find *B*.
If you don't, find the `[NSWorkspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:]` and then use one of the `[NSWorkspace launchApplication:]` varieties.

Comment: This looks neat, but we have to support 10.5. Any pointers to solutions for that? I assume with GUI app you mean Application Kit based?

Comment: @gf - yes, because `NSWorkspace` is an AppKit class.  For 10.5, use `-[NSWorkspace launchedApplications]` and iterate through the array to see if you find B.  If you don't, find the `[NSWorkspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:]` and then use one of the `[NSWorkspace launchApplication:]` varieties.

Comment: I should also add that if either A or B is a non-bundle app, then @Chuck's approach is better.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out tomorrow.

Comment: ... took the liberty of editing the 10.5 information into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the other application is a command-line app or can behave like one, NSTask is the best choice — you can launch another program and define its standard input, output and error streams. If this is a GUI app, you can use Scripting Bridge or NSWorkspace + use your own communication protocol with NSConnection, etc.